# Paypal error 580029 One of the required parameters for subscription is missing

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

When I try to make a preapproval this message comes up instead of showing me the Paypal login screen. Usually it is more specific, but now it just says "One of the required parameters for subscription is missing", so

I would like to know what is the parameter missing?. 
Is this related to the APP ID?

It worked fine in Sandbox but when going live I have this error.

**Preapproval adaptive-preapproval**

**Error**

```
PayPal\Types\AP\PreapprovalResponse Object
[responseEnvelope] => PayPal\Types\Common\ResponseEnvelope Object
    (
        [timestamp] => 2016-01-06T11:02:03.894-08:00
        [ack] => Failure
        [correlationId] => 4d382b98c6be4
        [build] => 17820627
    )

[preapprovalKey] => 
[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => PayPal\Types\Common\ErrorData Object
            (
                [errorId] => 580029
                [domain] => PLATFORM
                [subdomain] => Application
                [severity] => Error
                [category] => Application
                [message] => One of the required parameters for subscription is missing
                [exceptionId] => 
                [parameter] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => PayPal\Types\Common\ErrorParameter Object
                            (
                                [name] => 
                                [value] => Subscription
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

**Request**

```
PayPal\Types\AP\PreapprovalRequest Object
[requestEnvelope] => PayPal\Types\Common\RequestEnvelope Object
    (
        [detailLevel] => 
        [errorLanguage] => en_US
    )

[clientDetails] => PayPal\Types\Common\ClientDetailsType Object
    (
        [ipAddress] => 
        [deviceId] => 
        [applicationId] => MY_APP_NAME
        [model] => 
        [geoLocation] => 
        [customerType] => 
        [partnerName] => 
        [customerId] => 
    )

[cancelUrl] => http://localhost/auction/create-auction/?post_new_step=1&projectid=181
[currencyCode] => CAD
[dateOfMonth] => 
[dayOfWeek] => 
[endingDate] => 2016-02-05Z
[maxAmountPerPayment] => 
[maxNumberOfPayments] => 
[maxNumberOfPaymentsPerPeriod] => 1
[maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments] => 1.5
[paymentPeriod] => NO_PERIOD_SPECIFIED
[returnUrl] => http://localhost/auction/?page_id=10&finalize=1&post_new_step=4&projectid=181
[memo] => 
[ipnNotificationUrl] => 
[senderEmail] => 
[startingDate] => 2016-01-06Z
[pinType] => 
[feesPayer] => 
[displayMaxTotalAmount] => 1
[requireInstantFundingSource] => 
[sender] =>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced the same issue.

I resolved it by filling out all of the "Max*" fields.

In my case, I was missing the "maxNumberOfPaymentsPerPeriod" field.

Successfully created a approval token for a "one-time" payment with the following request:

```
cancelUrl:  "http://localhost:55182/Booking/InitialBookingRequest?StartDate=7/1/2016 1:15:00 AM&EndDate=7/1/2016 2:15:00 AM&ListingId=119295&bookingId=90802"   string
clientDetails:  null
currencyCode:   "USD"
dateOfMonth:    null
dayOfWeek:  null
displayMaxTotalAmount:  null
endingDate: "2016-07-15"
feesPayer:  null    
ipnNotificationUrl: "http://localhost:55182/home/handler"   
maxAmountPerPayment:    5.00    
maxNumberOfPayments:    1
maxNumberOfPaymentsPerPeriod:   1   
maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments:    5.00    
memo:   null    
paymentPeriod:  null    
pinType:    null    
requireInstantFundingSource:    null    
returnUrl:  "http://localhost:55182/booking/Success?StartDate=7/1/2016 1:15:00 AM&EndDate=7/1/2016 2:15:00 AM&ListingId=119295&bookingId=90802" string
sender: null    
senderEmail:    null
startingDate:   "2016-06-30"
```

Answer (score 1):

We have been battling with this issue too, and it seems it comes up on the internet quite a bit. Unfortunately, the PayPal documentation lists most fields as *Optional*, when they aren't.

What fields are actually optional depends on the type of Pre-approval you are using (there is Subscription / One-time / On-demand), but none of this seems to be mentioned in the [PayPal API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/).

Looking at your request, I believe the one field you will also need to specify is `maxAmountPerPayment`, which in your case would be the same as `maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments`

Although the error is cryptic, it is in fact informing you that for a Subscription type of Pre-approval, you are missing some required fields. Unfortuantely these required fields are not documented. If it turns out `maxAmountPerPayment` doesn't work, my advice would be to start populating each field and testing until the request passes! Good luck.